# Example code for SSL client authentication in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ssl, ssl-certificate, authentication

Folks,

Can anyone provide a working example of how to do SSL client authentication in ruby 1.8.7? For the record, I am attempting to use a GoDaddy certification to perform an authenticated post request to the [Windows Phone push notification service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221551.aspx). In this case, my command-line client is using a certificate like an API key or bearer token.

I supply GoDaddy a mydomain.com.key file, and GoDaddy supplies me with a gd_bundle.crt file and a mydomain.com.crt file.

On my Net::HTTP object, I have set these parameters:

```
my_cert = File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "mydomain.com.crt")) # from godaddy
my_key = File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "mydomain.com.key")) # i made

http.use_ssl = true
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(my_cert)
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(my_key)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

But the push notification service continues to report a 403 error saying "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied".

Since someone out there is doing push successfully I assume the way I have configured my Net::HTTP object in ruby is incorrect. Does anyone have sample code for how I can use ruby to perform SSL client authentication?